# Carousels don't work when using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a responsive image slider using css. I did it by using this example http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-thumb-preview-in-carousel-indicators. The sliders work automatically except when I click the carousel, instead of sliding the images, it goes to another page. How to stop this? is it because it is conflicting with angularjs?

Here the code:

```
<div id="thumbnail-preview-indicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/abstract_wallpaper_1.png" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="1">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/435523.jpg" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/wallpaper-1356336.jpg" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item slides active">
            <div class="slide-1"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Hi there! How was your day?</h1>
                    <p>This is the slide 1. Next --></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#/" role="button">I'm Fine</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item slides">
            <div class="slide-2"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Welcome back! how do you do?</h1>
                    <p>This is slide 2. Moving on... </p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#/" role="button">Great! Thanks.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item slides">
            <div class="slide-3"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>You are back again! Need anything?</h1>
                    <p>This is slide 3. And the last one</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#/" role="button">Yes peace :)</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

This is the app.js.

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('myWeb',
    [
        'ngRoute'
    ]);
console.log('app');
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        });
    $routeProvider
        .when('/signup',{
            templateUrl: 'signup.html',
            controller: 'SignupController'
        });
    $routeProvider
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'contact.html',
                controller: 'ContactController'
            });
    $routeProvider
        .when('/about',{
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        });

    $routeProvider
    .when('/t-and-c-m',
    {
        activatetab: '#t-and-c-m'
    });

}]);
```

Do i need to configure in angularjs too, to work out this? Help would be appreciated as i'm a beginner to angularjs.

The css for the question as follows

```
#thumbnail-preview-indicators {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-1, 
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-2,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-3 {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators,
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides,
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-1, 
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-2,
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-3 {
      height: 480px;
    }

#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-1{
    background-image: url(../assets/images/abstract_wallpaper_1.png);
}

#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-2{
    background-image: url(../assets/images/435523.jpg);
}

#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-3{
    background-image:url(../assets/images/wallpaper-1356336.jpg);
}

#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-inner .item .carousel-caption {
  top: 20%;
  bottom: inherit;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 8px;  
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li > .thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li:hover > .thumbnail,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active > .thumbnail {
  display: block;
  opacity: .8;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active > .thumbnail:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 480px) {    
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li,
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active {
      width: 50px;
      height: 8px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li > .thumbnail {
       width: 50px;
       left: 50%;
       margin-top: -50px;
       margin-left: -25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: href="#/" should rather be href="#"

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ for this? It is easier to provide a solution that way.

Comment: It is a mess in jsfiddle. I haven't use jsfiddle in my life so here i add the css file also. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0wahLkc7/3/) the code for any analysis. but I think it will not work. :(

Comment: I don't believe bootstrap carousel is compatible with angularJS due to their use of the # for the next and prev buttons. Try using this instead: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap Carousel is not compatible with AngularJs due to their use of # within the next/prev buttons.

You can either try to rewrite the bootstrap code for carousel.js or use other projects like this:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: OK I'll try and see to get this to work by using `ui.bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have plenty of `<a href='#/'>` which will indeed load a new page when they are clicked on. What is the intent here ? Most likely, you want to have a `ng-click="myfunc()"` with a declaration

```
$scope.myfunc = function() {....}
```

to do something else when the user clicks on the link. That declaration would be done in the controller for that part of the page (I would create a `CarouselController` specifically set on the first div with `ng-controller="CarouselController`, so that you can reuse it in other places if need be).

Comment: Yes. I'm aware that it will take to the default page because of the app. I will change that later. I'm intending to load popular products or so on.

Comment: how about the carousel do i have to configure the `#thumbnail-preview-indicators` in the `app.js` too